# Deleting Parse files

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

If I have a Parse object with a file attribute on it and then I delete the original object.

1. Does it delete the orphaned file?
2. If not, how do I delete the file?

I'm doing everything in cloud code using Javascript trying to put an "After delete" function together and cascading the delete down.

**EDIT**

OK, a quick test later. The files are not deleted. They are orphaned. So, how to delete the file in cloud code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is pressing the clean up button located in the settings page of your app (I saw that somebody else had mentioned deleting via the [REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest#files-deleting)).

[image: Screenshot]

*[You can delete files that are referenced by objects using the REST API. You will need to provide the master key in order to be allowed to delete a file.](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#files-retrieving)*

*[If your files are not referenced by any object in your app, it is not possible to delete them through the REST API. You may request a cleanup of unused files in your app's Settings page. Keep in mind that doing so may break functionality which depended on accessing unreferenced files through their URL property. Files that are currently associated with an object will not be affected.](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#files-retrieving)*

Comment: Excuse my french but f*ck that. Worst way of dealing with files ever. Been trying for the past hour to delete files and failed every time. Switching to the "Clean Up Files" method. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

There is a REST API for that, see [here](https://parse.com/docs/rest#files-deleting)

Comment: Surely there is a Javascript API for this? When deleting a record (for instance) I can use `Parse.Object.destroy();` is there nothing like that for files?

Comment: "You can delete files that are referenced by objects using the REST API. You will need to provide the master key in order to be allowed to delete a file." [Source](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#files-retrieving)

Comment: Quote: "Note that deleting a PFObject with a file associated with it will not delete the file. All files stored on Parse should be deleted by using the above explained API."

Comment: Well, that seems stupid. LOL! Thanks, will use the REST API :D

Comment: OK, so I've given up with that. Pretty much zero documentation about how to do anything with that REST API.

Comment: @Fogmeister I would have to agree. The API does look like an afterthought.

Comment: @Donal not your fault I know :) thanks for helping though :D I'll maybe come back to using an API when something better is implemented.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, you literally just call destroy() on the File in the new open-source SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers already pointed out the proper links... The following shows how I did it from within the browser...

```
    // 1. in a browser console, go to their domain do avoid cross-domain failure later
    //    (paste this by itself)
    document.location.href='https://api.parse.com';

    // 2. load up jquery 
    //    (paste this and the rest of the script into the console only after the page url above loads)
    (function(){
      var newscript = document.createElement('script');
         newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
         newscript.async = true;
         newscript.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js';
      (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(newscript);
    })();

    // the goods
    function deleteParseFile(appId, masterKey, filename)
    {
        var serverUrl = 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/' + filename;
        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            beforeSend: function(request) {
                  request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", appId);
                  request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Master-Key", masterKey);
                },
            url: serverUrl,
            success: function(results) {
                console.log('success:', results)
            }, error: function(error) {
                console.log('error:', error);
            }
        });
    }

    // 3. set the file you want deleted... and delete it
    var appId = "<YOUR_APPLICATION_ID>";
    var masterKey = "<YOUR_MASTER_KEY>";

    // this filename can be found in the file object or the parse image URL
    var filename = "tfss-abcd1234-dcba-4321-1a2b-112233aabbcc-my-file.gif";

    deleteParseFile(appId, masterKey, filename);
```